# Do I need to install something from Crystal Reports on the server?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am developing a web application project in Visual Studio 2010. It is published to a Windows 2008 server.

I have added references to:

CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine

CrystalDecisions.Shared

CrystalDecisions.Web

And added CrystalReportViewer to a .aspx page.

The crystal report files that are to be displayed by the viewer are on the server the application is published to.

If I run the application locally - it works fine and the reports are displayed in the viewer.

If I publish the application to the server, it falls over with a 'log4net' missing assembly message.

Do I need to install something from Crystal Reports on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes- you will need to install the relevant Crystal Reports runtimes/redistributes;

http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp

Should have what you need.

If you get trouble with versions try fixing by adding this to your app/web .config:

```
<runtime> 
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="xx.x.xxxx.x" newVersion="yy.y.yyyy.y"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="xx.x.xxxx.x" newVersion="yy.y.yyyy.y"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="xx.x.xxxx.x" newVersion="yy.y.yyyy.y"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        ...
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. So I figure I need to install the SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4 (64-bit) on the server. How can I tell if it is already on there?

Comment: From memory it will appear in control panel, add/remove programs

Comment: I'm always baffled by this stuff. I have added a reference to CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.dll and published the site.

When I try to run the site I am told the assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer.dll Version 13.0.2000.0 is missing. On my local machine the version referenced is 13.0.0.99

 Why is the server looking for 13.0.2000.0? What told it to do that? You upload a site with a reference to a dll version 13.0.0.99 and the server decides to look for 13.0.2000.0 How can I get my local machine to reference what is presumably a later version?

Comment: I just added some code which is sometimes neccessary to "patch" the version number. I have to admit Crystal is a bit of a PITA!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve that error my just ticking the Enable 32 bit application to true from advanced settings in IIS. Click the app pool you selected>adv settings>a dialog will pop up.